# How can i access view from IBAction method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 4 view in a windows. All view link to same method -(IBAction)touched:(id)sender

how can i make when touch at view 1 only view 1 background color is change.
but the left 3 view are not.
also if i touch another view only view that touching change background color but other view is not change.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method of your `UIViewController`

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if([event touchesForView:view1] != nil) 
        //View1 touched
    else if ([event touchesForView:view2] != nil) 
        //View2 touched
    else if ([event touchesForView:view3] != nil) 
        //View3 touched
    else if ([event touchesForView:view4] != nil) 
        //View4 touched 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag your view by setting its 'tag' property and in your (IBAction)touched:(id)sender you inspect the tag value like

```
if (((UIView*)sender).tag == 1) {
    //Do something for the view with tag value 1
}
```